# Getting an error when sending an image over HTTP POST

Tags: php, api, http, post, curl

So I'm trying to "upload" a PNG from my server to another. So I need to send an HTTP POST with an image in it. This is my HTML

```
<form action="decode.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select PDF to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload PDF" name="submit">
</form>
```

And then my script trying to upload the PNG

```
//Get file contents
$fcont = file_get_contents('pQV0s.png');

$ch = curl_init();
$postfields = array(
    "MAX_FILE_SIZE" => 1048576,
    "file" => $fcont
    );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
exit();
```

But all I get in response is

> en: malformed 'read-qr-code' API request. Please consider the API documentation at http://goqr.me/api/doc/read-qr-code

I'm not really sure what that could mean because I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to get the file data rather than just sending the tmp_name.  Try using file_get_contents

Comment: Just tried what you suggested. Same issue @Phil_1984_

Comment: Try putting MAX_FILE_SIZE before the file.  The API specifically says it needs to come before the file.

Comment: Still the same error coming through @Phil_1984_

Comment: Remove the @ sign, you dont need it.  It is probably corrupting the data.

Comment: Sadly the same issue :( @Phil_1984_

Comment: How big is the file you are trying to send?  The API only allows 1MB max.  I just copied your code as it appears above, and it works fine for me using a 3KB png file.  So I guess my comments above are incorrect since your code does work.

Comment: I got 23KB on my file @Phil_1984_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67068/discussion-between-phil-1984-and-idris).